# Angular 4: How to pass formGroup by route navigation

Tags: angular

I have one component which is expecting one formGroup.
Now with my home page what I am trying to do is that whenever I click one button then it will call one function  which then runs 
`this.router.navigate(['my-component']);`

Now I need to pass formGroup through this but I am not able to get it that how it can be done. I tried queryParams but no success.

It would be great if I can pass formGroup to this `my-component` component. Any help

Comment: How have you written your code using query params? Can you display it here?

Comment: By the way, the data property is only for router config. If you need to pass complex data, use a shared service. query params should just be used for one or two parameters which are not supposed to be hidden. If your form data should be secured, use shared service instead

Answer (score 0):

Create a shared `service` with a variable that is a `behaviorSubject`.

Create a `set` method and a `get` method like this :

```
public set $yourVariable(...data_input){
   //your logic
}

public get $yourVariable(){
  return this.yourVariable.asObservable();
}
```

in your component ( or where you need datas) `inject` the service. Add a variable called `isAlive` setted on true by default. Add `NgOnDestroy` method with this code :

`this.isAlive = false`

This will prevent the subscribtion you'll write to be active when your component isn't istanced.

Add or modify your `OnInit` method in this way :

```
...
this.yourService.$yourVariable
.takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
.subscribe( event => {
   //your logic here
});
...
```

If your component requires data `before` the service get injected, just add a `.filter` to prevent data to get render before your request has done.